# Maven project in IntelliJ just went all bad on me

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have a multi maven project in IntelliJ (11) that was working fine.

I think I select some popup option and didnt' even notice, and now all the modules are now registering correctly when I see the project structure.

I don't see any maven modules, and when I try and import an existing maven module it works but then shows that all my dependencies in the pom are not valid like:

Module 'mymodule': invalid item "Maven org.springframework-spring....." in the dependency list.

SO when I click 'OK', it asks me to remove the module from the project since it was removed from maven.

How can I fix this?

In the project window all the module parent folders are not in bold anymore either.

Very confused as to what happend.

Comment: I use the latest release of Intellij IDEA(11.1.1) and get the same problem as you. But when I build the project or module using maven, everything works fine.

Comment: Did you try reimporting your maven projects? Whenever you have issues with your project just do that. The other thing you can do is re-import your project from scratch - close it and re-open the root pom.xml from 'open project' dialog

Answer (score 3):

I assume your project and all the modules build fine from the command line even when removing all the artifacts that are build by the project are removed from your love local repository and in offline mode (-o).

Try opening the parent pom as the project and when asked have Intellij delete all previous project files.

Comment: IntelliJ build its own dependency structure from the pom. Sometimes the two get out of sync.